# AutoMapper ResolveUsing using generics cause "Value supplied is of type X but expected Y" error

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a scenario where I have to map a DTO to a domain object using AutoMapper. This mapping needs some complex managment so I have created a Custom Value Resolver. I want to get `Foo` from `FooDTO`. The only difference between these two objects is that `Foo` have a `ICollection<Child>` and `FooDTO` have a `TrackedData<ChildDTO>`, where `TrackeData<T>` is an object with 3 `ICollection<T>`.
This is my simplified scenario:

```
public class TrackedData<T>
{
    public ICollection<T> Updated { get; set; }
    public ICollection<T> Created { get; set; }
    public ICollection<T> Deleted { get; set; }

    public TrackedData()
    {
        Updated = new List<T>();
        Created = new List<T>();
        Deleted = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private List<Child> _childs;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Childs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_childs == null)
                _childs = new List<Child>();
            return _childs;
        }
        set
        {
            _childs = (List<Child>)value;
        }
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class FooDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TrackedData<ChildDTO> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDTO
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(TrackedData<>), typeof(TrackedData<>));
        Mapper.CreateMap<ChildDTO, Child>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FooDTO, Foo>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Childs, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TrackedDataResolver<ChildDTO, Child>>());

        FooDTO fooDTO = CreateFakeFooDTO();

        Foo foo = Mapper.Map<FooDTO, Foo>(fooDTO);
    }

    private static FooDTO CreateFakeFooDTO() { /* omitted for simplicity */ }

    private static TrackedData<ChildDTO> CreateFakeTrackedDataChildDTO() { /* omitted for simplicity */ }

    private static ICollection<ChildDTO> CreateFakeListChildDTO() { /* omitted for simplicity */ }

    private static ChildDTO CrateFakeChildDTO(){ /* omitted for simplicity */ }
}

public class TrackedDataResolver<TSource, TDestination> : ValueResolver<TrackedData<TSource>, ICollection<TDestination>>
{
    protected override ICollection<TDestination> ResolveCore(TrackedData<TSource> source)
    {
        TrackedData<TDestination> trackedDestination = new TrackedData<TDestination>();
        ICollection<TDestination> destination = new List<TDestination>();

        trackedDestination = Mapper.Map<TrackedData<TSource>, TrackedData<TDestination>>(source);

        foreach (var o in trackedDestination.Created)
        {
            // Do stuff...
            destination.Add(o);
        }
        foreach (var o in trackedDestination.Updated)
        {
            // Do stuff...
            destination.Add(o);
        }
        foreach (var o in trackedDestination.Deleted)
        {
            // Do stuff...
            destination.Add(o);
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

When this line is executed

```
Foo foo = Mapper.Map<FooDTO, Foo>(fooDTO);
```

I get this error:

> {"Value supplied is of type AutoMapperDemo.FooDTO but expected AutoMapperDemo.TrackedData'1[AutoMapperDemo.ChildDTO]. Change the value resolver source type, or redirect the source value supplied to the value resolver using FromMember.\r\nValue supplied is of type AutoMapperDemo.FooDTO but expected AutoMapperDemo.TrackedData'1[AutoMapperDemo.ChildDTO].Change the value resolver source type, or redirect the source value supplied to the value resolver using FromMember."}

[Source code](https://github.com/josmonver/AutoMapperValueResolverIssue.git) is avaiable in Github: https://github.com/josmonver/AutoMapperValueResolverIssue.git
Any idea why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bringing heavy logic into your mapper you may implement something like `UnionAll` method (Updated + Created + Deleted) in your `TrackedData<T>` class and map it:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<FooDTO, Foo>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Childs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UnionAll()));
```

Comment: This works. In fact, I tested a similar solution before posting my question. But in my real scenario I don't want my DTOs to know anything about my domain objects (Foo is a domain object). My solution, for the moment, consists of having a map function that receives a TrackedData<ChildDTO> object and do this:
`Mapper.CreateMap<FooDTO, Foo>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Childs, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => MapperTrackedData.Map<ChildDTO, Child>(s.Childs)))`
Where MapperTrackedData.Map() is like the custom value resolver TrackedDataResolver.
Anyway, I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong